# SphinxQl add comments - How to write in log files

Tags: sphinx, sphinxql

I have fetching records from SphinxQl . Here i have to be find out howmany sphinxQL querys coming to server. As the same i have to be know any options is there to add comments in sphinxQl query. Please help me to findout the solutions.

Answer (score 2):

```
... OPTION comment='This is a comment to be entered in the log file'
```

From the documentation:
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sphinxql-reference

Comment: When using PHP ```SphinxClient```, you can add "comment" as third parameter like ```$sphinxClient->query("searchstring", "main", "this is comment line")``` as from here: http://php.net/manual/en/sphinxclient.query.php

Answer (score 0):

(to complete, but  the  other answer is more linked to your problem)

with SphinxSE

WHERE  query="(....);comment=This is a comment to be entered in the log file"